# Is it safe to move partitions like that?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, partition, grub

I have SSD with installed both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. Windows has it's own UEFI starting partition and Linux has Legacy BIOS one. I would like to completely scratch Windows installation from this drive and give the whole space to Linux but I don't want to cause any damage to partition with /boot. My partitons:

[image]

/dev/sda[1-4] are basically Windows stuff which I want to delete.
/dev/sda8 is my data directory, it can be deleted.
/dev/sda5 is Linux /boot partition which should be untouched.
/dev/sda6 is my root directory which I want to move back to the place in which currently sda1 lives on.

Is it safe to delete /dev/sda[1-4,8], move /dev/sda5 back and then move the whole /dev/sda6 back? What are any other proposals to avoid loosing my linux installation and boot partition? I'm not an experienced user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about UEFI, but it sounds like you don't need UEFI anyway.  You should be able to do what you said, delete the first four partitions, and then move 5 and 6 to become 1 and 2.  But you will likely need to run `grub-install` or `update-grub` after doing so, so make sure you have Linux boot media handy.  You can probably do it from within the system you are running when you move the partitions, but you might need to use boot media, especially if anything goes wrong.

BTW, if you're not an experienced user, now's a great time to become one.  ;)  If you don't need to keep anything on your Linux partitions, then get your boot/install disc, and experiment away!  If anything goes wrong, just delete all the partitions and reinstall.  :)